# How to make a polygon attach to a point at a 3 o'clock position

Tags: java, polygon, radius

I'm working on a project and I have most of it done but I'm having trouble seeing how to get the coordinates to line up. I'm stuck and I'm not sure how to get a point to be at 3 o'clock and I'm stuck. I've tried finding examples but all I see is polygons that don't need to lineup with anything. Any help?

The instructions: Suppose an n-sided regular polygon is centered at (0, 0) with one point at the 3 o’clock position, as shown in Figure 5.4. Write a program that prompts the user to enter the number of the sides, the radius of the bounding circle of a polygon, and displays the coordinates of the corner points on the polygon.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Polygon {

public static void main(String[] args) {

 Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.print("Enter the number of sides: ");
 int sides = input.nextInt();

 System.out.print("Enter the radius of the bounding circle: ");
 double radius = input.nextDouble();
 input.close();

 System.out.println("The coordinates of the points on the polygon are");
 for (int i = 0; i < sides; i++) {

     double x = radius * java.lang.Math.sin(2.0 * java.lang.Math.PI / sides * i);
     double y = radius * java.lang.Math.cos(2.0 * java.lang.Math.PI / sides * i);
     System.out.print("(");
     System.out.printf("%.2f", x);
     System.out.print(" ");
     System.out.printf("%.2f",y);
     System.out.print(")");
     System.out.println();
     }

   }
}
```

Comment: Where's the `Figure 5.4`? It would be more comprehensible if your convert radians to degrees as you can picture it out.

Answer (score 1):

You need to switch your `sin` and `cos` expressions. The the first point of your polygon will then always lie at `(radius, 0)`, i.e. aligned with the 3-o'clock position.

```
     double x = radius * java.lang.Math.cos(2.0 * java.lang.Math.PI / sides * i);
     double y = radius * java.lang.Math.sin(2.0 * java.lang.Math.PI / sides * i);
```